# Google Sheets SHOW the apostrophe before text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column in Google Sheets with strings.

Some of the rows start with an apostrophe `'`, some don't. But Google assumed that the apostrophe is *because it's a text* instead of letting it be *part of the text*.

How do I make it show these apostrophes?

Comment: Hi @DanielMöller! I could help you to solve the apostrophe issue in an automatic way on all the rows. My code would be on [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), would it be a valid solution for your problem? Don't hesitate to ask me to clarificate how to use the code if you need some extra help.

Comment: Can't find your code.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned:

> Some of the rows start with an apostrophe `'`, some don't...
>   How do I make it show these apostrophes?

By **adding an extra apostrophe `'` in the beginning** of the cells.

---

### EDIT

Following the comments by OP

> That's inviable for 10000 rows.

and Liron

> You can do that with "`Find and replace`" - search for `^'` (caret and apostrophe) and replace it with `''` (two apostrophes), and select "`Search using regular expressions`" and "`Also search within formulas`".
>   That would change every apostrophe at the beginning of a cell to two apostrophes.

[image]

Comment: That's inviable for 10000 rows. I tried a formula, but then it starts showing all the apostrophes added with the formula.

Comment: You can do that with "Find and replace" - search for [^'] (caret and apostrophe) and replace it with [''] (two apostrophes), and select "Search using regular expressions" and "Also search within formulas". That would change every apostrophe at the beginning of a cell to two apostrophes. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLLAw.png.

Comment: Excellent. I also included your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following script as an answer. I assume that you have a column with a mix of strings, some being enclosed in `'` and some don't, like this example:

[image: Original data]

As shown on the picture, Sheets automatically hides the first `'`. To prevent this you have to add another `'` at the start of the string. You can do it with this code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    "{SPREADSHEET IDENTIFICATOR}").getSheets()[0];
  var dataColumn = 2;
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(1, dataColumn, dataSheet.getLastRow());
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      if (data[i][j].substr(-1, 1) == "'") {
        data[i][j] = "''" + data[i][j];
      }
    }
  }

  dataRange.setValues(data);
}
```

The former code will first use a combination of [`.openById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid), [`.getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets), [`.getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows) and [`.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to open the spreadsheet, open the sheet, get the data range and read its values respectively. Then, the code will iterate over every value to check if it ends in a `'`, and if it does, the script will add an extra `'` at the start of the string. The end result looks like this:

[image: Final data]

Please, ask me any question for additional help.

Comment: Good one. Does it detect the apostrophe "at the beginning"? Usual sheet formulas don't. But your code can be used without an "if" to add apostrophes to all rows and it would work, I think?

Comment: Hi @DanielMöller! Yes, that is correct: if you delete the `if` line (and its `}` below) it will add an extra apostrophe in every row. Please, tell me if your answer was useful or how I can further help you.